# Making sure "Get Value From User" dialog window is always on top with Robot Framework

Tags: macos, terminal, robotframework

I've been hitting my head on the wall with `Get Value From User`.

I wasn't sure it was working, then was told "Are you sure it's not behind the Terminal window?". I moved the terminal window, and, there the dialog was.

How would I make sure that the dialog opened by `Get Value From User` is always on top with macOSX Terminal?